# Vite main.js file not found error in console

Tags: typo3, vite, ddev

I try to setup vite for my typo3 website thats running on ddev docker.
"Npm run dev" and "npm run build" working fine in the console.

[npm run build] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM4eJ.jpg)

[npm run dev] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKtKR.jpg)

The Output is also saved correctly in Public/Vite/

Unfortunately my main.js can not be found.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1iFw.jpg)

**vite.config.js**

```
export const config = {
    target: 'es6',
    outDir: 'packages/colin_frontend/Resources/Public/Vite/',
    entry: 'src/js/main.js',
    watchIncludes: './src/**/**/**/.js',

    stylelint: {
        include: ['./src/scss/**/*.scss'],
        exclude: [
            /node_modules/,
        ],
    },
};

export const DDEV_HMR_PORT = 5173;
```

**vite.website.js**

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  resolve: { alias: { '@': '/src' } },
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
  }
  },
  publicDir: false,
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'src/js/main.js', // overwrite default .html entry
    },
    manifest: true, // generate manifest.json in outDir
    outDir: 'packages/colin_frontend/Resources/Public/Vite/', // ⚠️ `pnpm build` purges outDir
  },
  css: {
    devSourcemap: true, // disabled by default because of performance reasons
  }
})
```

I don't really know where the problem lies. Hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Comment: Is the path of main.js inside of your root-folder? See the parameter 'docroot' inside your ddev-configuration. That folder must be the parent of your path of main.js.

Comment: My docroot in the .ddev/config.yaml is "public". Do you mena that I have to move my main.js into the "public" folder?